# What's the concept of the Kṛityā (कृत्या)?

Tags: scripture, tantra, shukracharya, prahlada, demon

*Hiraṇyakaśipu*  via his guru, *Śukrācārya*, is said to have deployed [Kṛityā](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=zqIZDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT62&dq=Kritya%20prahlad&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjrxJCO1bbvAhVJlEsFHdW-CVoQ6AEwAHoECAUQAw#v=onepage&q=Kritya%20prahlad&f=false) to destroy *Prahlāda*. I have read that it's some kind of an ogress or an evil demoness.

What's a *Kṛityā*? Is it some *Māraṇa tantra (मारण तंत्र )* or some other kind of forbidden ritual?

What are some other instances of it being deployed against others in the scriptures, besides *Prahlāda*? And if it's forbidden, why would a great sage like *Śukrācārya* would use it (if he was indeed the one who did it), against an innocent child?

Comment: From [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/kritya) --- "1) Kṛtyā (कृत्या).—(KṚTYAKĀ) I. A Rākṣasī who is born when the black arts as enunciated in the Atharvaveda are practised to annihilate enemies. Kṛtyā may appear in male form too. Some of the activities of Kṛtyā are given below."

Comment: Thanks @Rickross,. Also, that account from the Mahabharata though, *Duryodhana* carried to *patala* by *Kṛityā* . Never knew about that. Adds some new perspective maybe, to his character sketch.

Comment: Kritya is a performable karma. So it can mean anything like curse, violence etc. Its mostly associated with evil karmas. In Atharaveda the term may be found at kanda 10 sukta 1 [krityaDushanm](http://vedicheritage.gov.in/samhitas/atharvaveda-samhitas/shaunaka-samhita/kanda-10-sukta-001/) and kanda 5 sukta 31 [krityaPariharnam](http://vedicheritage.gov.in/samhitas/atharvaveda-samhitas/shaunaka-samhita/kanda-05-sukta-031/)

Comment: @Proxy interesting!